# How do you get duplicates in a list in elixir?

Tags: functional-programming, elixir, reduce

If you want to get duplicates instead of uniq values in a list, how would you do this in a quick, dense script that uses pattern matching?

For example, with an input of `["ash", "bob", "cat", "bob", "ash"]` how could I get `["ash", "bob"]` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you specified you wanted a quick, dense script, I think you should consider this solution:

```
l = ["ash", "bob", "cat", "bob", "ash", "ash"]

# to get all duplicates
l -- Enum.uniq(l) # => ["bob", "ash", "ash"]

# to get a unique list of duplicates
Enum.uniq(l -- Enum.uniq(l)) # => ["bob", "ash"]
```

Comment: This is so similar to my own answer, and only 30 seconds difference in posting. Spooky...

Comment: This is about 2½ times slower but uses 7–10% less memory than than a more complex solution involving `group_by` and `filter` with a match. See this [benchmarking gist](https://gist.github.com/halostatue/4407dde79bb9c584abcf083f6b83b1ea) for the example code and output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

```
["ash", "bob", "cat", "bob", "ash"]
|> (&((&1 -- (&1 |> Enum.uniq())) |> Enum.uniq())).()
```

This is the same as doing:

```
my_list = ["ash", "bob", "cat", "bob", "ash"]
(my_list -- (my_list |> Enum.uniq())) |> Enum.uniq()
```

What is happening:

1. get a list of all the unique values (the complement to what we want): `my_list |> Enum.uniq()`
2. Use list subtraction to get the complement of these unique values.
3. Use another call to `Enum.uniq` to get these "duplicates" in unique list.

Comment: If the list is super big `--` could take forever..

Comment: @tblev is correct, see my comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a unique list of all duplicates

```
  def get_uniq_duplicates(all) do
    all |> Enum.reduce({[], []}, fn val, {once, duplicates} -> 
      if once |> Enum.member?(val) do 
        if duplicates |> Enum.member?(val) do
          {once, duplicates}
        else
          {once, duplicates ++ [val]}
        end 
      else
        {once ++ [val], duplicates}
      end
    end) |> elem(1)
  end
```

If you want a list of duplicates where only one copy of each value has been removed, eg. `["a", "b", "c", "c", "c"] -> ["c", "c"]`

Then you can use the simpler:

```
  def get_duplicates(all) do
    all |> Enum.reduce({[], []}, fn val, {once, duplicates} -> 
      if once |> Enum.member?(val) do 
        {once, duplicates ++ [val]}
      else
        {once ++ [val], duplicates}
      end
    end) |> elem(1)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Enum.group_by/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Enum.html#group_by/3)

```
["ash", "bob", "cat", "bob", "ash"]
|> Enum.group_by(&(&1))
|> Enum.filter(&((&1 |> Enum.count()) > 1))
|> Enum.map(&(&1 |> Enum.uniq()))
|> List.flatten()
```

This method supports searching structs for specific criteria.

Comment: This is inefficient because it is using `Enum.count()`. Better to use `&match?({_, [_, _ | _]}, &1)` as the filter function.